# How to determine the bandwidth of a AWS VPN connection between USA and France?

Tags: networking, vpn, amazon-web-services, bandwidth

An on-premises business in Bethesda, Maryland (USA) needs to access servers at their on-premises headquarters in Paris, France. They are currently using a local service provider and Pulse VPN, but their bandwidth is terrible (76 Mbps for office users, 4Mbps for remote workers in Canada).

How can I determine the cost, and more importantly, the bandwidth by using AWS? And how would this change be implemented?

I think this is whats called "AWS Site-to-Site VPN", no? I would like to clear up traffic congestion by leveraging the power of the AWS Global Network.

Thank you for your time, Sebastian

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/

Comment: An AWS Site-to-Site VPN is between a termination point inside AWS in one region and an external non-AWS site, using the external site's existing Internet connection.  It's not clear how you envision that service being able to mediate congestion on an existing Internet circuit.

Comment: Is it possible to route traffic from one office to another office through AWS?